# How to use StreamBuilder in Flutter To Stream Result from other StreamBuilder

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

I'm Have two StreamBulder 
First Stream in collection("Users").document("PhoneNum") which is content name and photo . 
sec Stream in Collection("Users").document("PhoneNum").document("FrindList")
which is content Frind PhoneNumber
i want to make First Stream get all result of sec Stream which i wan't to build Stream for all FrindList to get there name and photo and put it in ListView

and i try many code but it not work

i try to make like this

```
StreamBuilder(
  stream: Firestore.instance.collection("Users")
      .document(names)
      .snapshots(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
      return CircularProgressIndicator(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      );
    } else {
      List<Widget> list = [];
      var Frindname = snapshot.data["name"];
      var Frindpic = snapshot.data["ImageURL"];
      var Frindnum = snapshot.data["PhoneNumber"];
      try {

         return GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              var chatkey;
              if (widget.phoneN.compareTo(Frindnum) >
                  0) {
                chatkey = widget.phoneN + Frindnum;
                print(chatkey);
              } else {
                chatkey = Frindnum + widget.phoneN;
                print(chatkey);
              }

              Navigator.push(context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) {
                        return Chat();
                      }));
            },
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
                    bottom: Radius.elliptical(
                        100, 100),
                    top: Radius.elliptical(100, 100)),
                color: Colors.grey[200],),
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                        Frindpic), radius: 30,),
                  SizedBox(width: 10,),
                  Text(Frindname, style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.deepPurple,
                      fontSize: 18,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                ],
              ),
            ),

        );


      } catch (e) {
        return CircularProgressIndicator(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,);
      }
    }
  },

);
```

and then call this method inside other streambuilder

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                stream: Firestore.instance.collection("Users").document(widget.phoneN).collection("FrindList").snapshots(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                    CircularProgressIndicator(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                    );
                  }
                    try {
                    List<Widget> e = [];
                    snapshot.data.documents.forEach((d) {
                      print(d.data["FrindKey"]);
                      e.add(Streems(d.data["FrindKey"]));
                    }

                    );
                   return ListView(
                     children: e,
                   );

                     } catch (e) {
                      print(e);
                      return Text("No Friend Found", style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.deepPurple,
                          fontSize: 24,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),);
                    }
                  }

                 ),
```

and this is my database structure

[database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3bmf.png)

Answer (score 0):

it is resolved by used sec streambuilder inside listview.builder that returned from first streambuilder which is give the list of user and the sec streambuilder will get there details depending on result of first stream